# Battery terminal in wireless light switch corroded

Tags: battery, corrosion

I have a wireless light switch in my garage which uses 4 triple-A batteries. When the switch quit working recently, I took off the cover to replace the batteries and saw that the terminals were all corroded but the batteries themselves had no sign of corrosion on them.

I cleaned the terminals with vinegar, washed and dried them, and put the old batteries back in and the switch worked again.

Any idea what would make the terminals corrode without the batteries having any corrosion on them?

Comment: Putting non-rechargable batteries in a circuit that recharges batteries causes the batteries to emit gas that will cause corrosion.  AA alkalines are purposely vented non-obviously to prevent explosions when consumers attempt to charge or use in a device that also charges.  Make certain you are using the correct battery type for the device.

Comment: Also how hot does it get at that location?

Comment: do you live by an ocean?

Comment: @Tyson - The switch does not charge the batteries. In fact, I don't get why a switch which has the power to recharge batteries would need batteries. As to heat -- during the summer, it may get as high as 110 degrees in the garage.

Comment: @dandavis - No, I don't live by an ocean.  We do over-winter plants in the garage and they are located next to the switch and they are watered weekly.